# How to plot specific data from a dictionary in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dictionary with 10 elements like this

```
teams={'Manchester United':50, 'Liverpool': 70, 'Barcelona': 100, 'Real Madrid':90, 'Arsenal':30, 'Atletico':50}
```

Also I have another dictionary like this:

```
leagues={'England':['Manchester United', 'Liverpool', 'Arsenal'], 'Spain':['Barcelona', 'Real Madrid', 'Atletico']}
```

I only want to plot the graph of the English teams('Manchester United', 'Liverpool', 'Arsenal')
How do I do it?

This what I have written in my code so far

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(*zip(*teams.items()))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract the relevant information first, one approach is:

```
keys_ = [k for k in teams.keys() if k in leagues['England']]
vals_ = [teams.get(k) for k in keys_]
plt.bar(keys_, vals_)
plt.show()
```

The first list-comprehension will extract only the `keys_` that are part of the "England" league. The second will extract their corresponding values in the `teams` dictionary.

You can also compress it to a one-liner like:

```
[(k, teams[k]) for k in teams.keys() if k in leagues['England']]
```